# Column layout - how to set textfield witdth

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a formpanel which contains textfield items. [Here is a fiddle demonstrating my current screen](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mo6)

Is there anyway to make the width of the textfield take up less than the entire width of the column? Basically, I want the columns stay at the sizes they are (2 columns at 50% each), but I do not want the textfield taking up that entire space of the column.

Can this be achieved using a column layout like I have now?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want to achieve, in your example textfield is not fit column width on resize. If you want fixed width for textfield you can just use `width` property i guess.

Comment: Sorry - i might have been messing around in the fiddle when you looked at it. If you check now you can see what I'm talking about. I've tried what you suggest about  setting the textfield's width config, but it doesn't change anything.

To me it seems that if you put a textfield component as item in a column layout then the width configuration of the textfield becomes irrelevant. The textfield component will automatically fill the remaining columnWidth that is left after the fieldLabel. Can anyone confirm this?

I'm working in version 4.2 - havent tested how this works in later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just use [Ext.layout.container.Column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Column) wrong way.

In your example each textfield working as column itself and total columnWidth is 1.5.

> columnWidths must always add up to 1 (or 100%) when added together, otherwise your layout may not render as expected.

You have to use any container component as column and add textfields to this containers.

Check this [simple example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mrh).